# Fetch data from API inside cellForRowAt

Tags: swift, rest

I fetch data from an API, there are two different urls that I have to work with them, one of them give ma some information include an username, and I can use this username to get the full name of the user from an another url.

inside `cellForRowAt`, I get the username like that

```
self.timelineData[indexPath.row].owner.login
```

Then, I call the function to fetch data to get full name of the user

```
     var profile = Login(username: self.timelineData[indexPath.row].owner.login)
                profile.fetchProfileData{ result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        // Sucesss response from server
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.nameLabel.text = data[0].name
                        }
                    // failed response from server
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
```

It works and I get the full name, but there are two problems:

1- It take 3-4 seconds to get full name (it doesn't matter much)

2- sometimes the order of the full name isn't right and I have to scroll the collectionView to reload data to change the order to be right.

Could anyone help me to better doing that?
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should not fetch data in `cellForRow` method because it might be invoked multiple times when you scroll your collection view. 
Let's fetch your profile each time your ViewController (which contains the collectionView) appeared then reload the `collectionView`

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to a race condition in your code, you need to check to see if the data you are receiving is in fact meant for that cell. Check [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-race-conditions-in-swift/) on race conditions and rewrite your code outside of cellForRow and add a way to check if its the same cell it was writing to.

[More on Race conditions](https://medium.com/@chetan15aga/ios-concurrency-underlying-truth-1021a0bb2a98)